# How to output the solutions/answers in two or more columns in eqExam?

Tags: exam, acrotex

The default format for the solutions output in eqExam is in single column. Many times I just want to give an answer or a hint instead of a complete solution, so I would like to output the answers in the end of worksheets using eqExam in two or more columns as most textbooks do. I would like to know how to modify the eqexam.sty to achieve this.